# Check string in textbox with an event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm wondering if there is a way to use an event to check a string in a textBox in a windows form before the user clicks on the OK button?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the KeyDown, KeyPress, or KeyUp event.

A full list of events can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_events.aspx

It's all alphabetical, so scroll down to Key....

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to use the Validating event of the textbox.  This way, your validation routine runs when the user attempts to leave the textbox.